# Php store html and php in variable as string,but can't store if

Tags: php, html

```
$store="";
$store.=<tr><td>'.$row["cus_id"].'</td></tr>';
```

above code is no problem
but when i put if inside will come out error

```
$store.=<tr><td>'.if(!empty($row["cus_id"])){echo $row["cus_id"];}.'</td></tr>';
```

how to put if statement inside the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways is to use a function to parse the data:

```
function checkdata($string1){

   if (!empty($string1)) {
      return $string1;
    } else {
      return "";
  }

}
```

So the code will be :

```
<?php

function checkdata($string1){

   if (!empty($string1)) {
      return $string1;
    } else {
      return "";
  }

}

/////////////////////////

$store="";
$store.='<tr><td>'. checkdata($row["cus_id"]) .'</td></tr>';

echo $store;

?>
```

Note: In your question. you have missed out a quotation mark in `<tr><td>'`

Comment: OMG ,thanks a lot , i spent much time still not get it until you all come out

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($row["cus_id"])) {
    $cusId = $row["cus_id"]);
} else {
    $cusId = '';
}

$store .= '<tr><td>' . $cusId . '</td></tr>';
```